# How can I add extra column parameters to insert on sentitems from inbox gammu?

Tags: python, mysql, gammu

Currently I request SMS from a .com Server on a Server Machine that currently holds the USB Devices (wavecom) So far everything its ok. But I've encounter a issue where I need 2 values smsid,appid that I save on my inbox gammu table when I request them from .com server.

after gammu sents the sms inserts the delivery status on another table called sentitems. And I need a way to add this 2 columns with the values comming from inbox to sentitems so another cronjob can send the delivery report to the server and update the status.

There is a way to edit the source code of gammu and add this 2 columns?

Comment: So far I added a way to pass values o sentitems and its over CreatorID this column its copied from outbox I am passing them value1:value2 its not the best way to do it but its a start.

Answer (score 0):

You can add any field to Gammu SMSD databases as long as they have default values Gammu will work just fine.

You can also [customize any SQL queries](https://wammu.eu/docs/manual/smsd/sql.html) in case you want Gammu to insert something into these fields.